# QlikView - Apply different collors on concatenated values

Tags: concatenation, qlikview, textcolor

I have a small issue on QlikView, i m trying to apply different colors on concatenated values, when in separated columns, color works fine no big deal, but concatenated none is applied:

code on value definition: `=concat(Milestones,' / ')`

code on Text color under value definition:
 `=if(Status='Finished',Green(),if(Status='In Progress',Blue(), if(Status='Overdue',Red())))`

i ve tried something like `=concat(
Milestones,if(Status='Finished',Green(),if(Status='In Progress',Blue(), if(Status='Overdue',Red()))),' / ')` in the value definition, but it gets me an unpleasant error.

Hope i ve expressed my issue well, Thank u in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you concat the fields in the expression you now have many lines of data on one line. When you have them in separate columns they will appear on separate lines.Have a look at the difference between these two tables

[image: Concat vs Natural Straight Table]

QlikView no longer knows which of the statuses is the correct one for each id since there are multiple possibilities. So it can't evaluate an answer which means it can't give you a colour.

The way to fix this is to give it something to look for. I would do it like this. (My test data is slightly different to yours but the important part is the `index()>0` which is a function to find a given piece of text in a larger string and then return the numeric position, 0 means not found, anything bigger than 0 is found.

```
if(index(concat(Status,'/'),'Resolved')>0,lightGreen(),
if(index(concat(Status,'/'),'New')>0,lightRed()))
```

That should give you something like this.

[image: Coloured Text]

The order of teh nested if will be important as the first true will be the assigned colour, so if things can be In Progress and Overdue you should test for Overdue first.

Comment: well, whats causing the issue is that i m trying to color an object 'MILSTONES' based on the stat of another object 'STATUS', it works when they re separated, but when concatenated it doesn t know what to do

Comment: Have you got a small sample set of data I can Play around with? I suspect it is the same problem because concat turns many lines into one line. Then if there are multiple statuses you need to reduce that to only one as well or QlikView wont know what to do. I'm sure we can make it work.

Comment: I guess i didnt express my need well i m sorry for that, so i ll add: on the QV table, we only wanna display 'MIilestones' values, (from where we have `=concat(Milestones,' / ')` in the value definition) and we want to color every milestone according to the status value (from where we put this on the test color `=if(Status='Finished',Green(),if(Status='In Progress',Blue(), if(Status='Overdue',Red())))` and that s where we have the issue when concatenation is on the play, nothing is colored, but when in single line, it s colored correctly of course

Comment: Ok, so you would want different colours for each word in the same string. That I do not believe is possible is standard QlikView as it applies the formatting to the entire cell not to each character in the cell.

Comment: Alright, i have to drop that one then. thank you for your patient replies @The Budac